# Permission denied (publickey): error while copy file to linux server

Tags: linux, permissions, putty

I have configured the LDAP server and created groups and users. Then I installed the packages nss-pam-ldapd, `openldap-clients`, `sssd`, `openssl` on client machine. both client and LDAP server are configured on AWS instance.

To sync user of LDAP server with client I am trying to copy the `ldap.pem` to the client machine but I am getting permission denied error. Below is my command and error:

```
scp root@ip-xx-x-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:/etc/openldap/cacerts/ldap1_pubkey.pem /etc/openldap/certs
```

**ERROR**:

> Permission denied (publickey)

I am using putty. To authenticate both LDAP server and client in putty I have used putty private key which is generated from the key pair used while creating the instances on AWS.

When I am executing the below command it prompts to enter passphrase and when I leave it empty it give Permission denied error.

```
scp -i .ssh/authorized_keys2 root@ip-xx-x-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:/etc/openldap/cacerts/ldap1_pubkey.pem /etc/openldap/certs
```

What passphrase should I enter ?

Can anyone please help me out to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you are able to login to both servers using putty on your desktop. In this case the simplest approach to copy the file between VMs would be to copy it to your desktop and then to the second machine  for instance using winscp.

Comment: My VMs are authenticated with a key. How can I connect to VM from winscp using the key ?

Comment: "**Configure WinSCP Session**

When configuring session, specify path to your private key on SSH > Authentication page of Advanced Site Settings dialog.

Alternatively, load the private key into Pageant. " [more here - above is a quote](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_public_key)

There is also video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5T1Ahy2RkM)